# How to store git repository with submodules as a single file on local repository?

Tags: git

I have a scenario where there is a git repository with two submodules. They all exist on the public github. I unable to clone them due work related IT restrictions. I have decided to store them on local work network Git server. However, for reasons outside of my control, I cannot have 3 local repositories but just one. Thus, I am unable to store the submodules as separate repositories.

I am trying to find a way of bundling up the entire folder structure which contains the main repository and its submodules, into a single object and commit that into the local git repository. The submodule data must be pushed up along with the main repository.

Can this be done in a Git specific way or do I just zip everything and push up the zip file?

Comment: Whatever the details they can be dealt with, but you're going to have to provide them, what you're actually trying to do here. What's this "local work network Git server"? Git doesn't need "network Git servers" at all, they're conveniences. Google up "Git sneakernet" for a starter kit on the tools about dealing with firewalled systems. Explain your exact working environment, the tools you use, the work flow you're trying to fit this in to.

Comment: My workplace have their own Git. The work repositories are stored on it. I can git clone from there but not git clone from public Github. This is where the problem lies. Now there are certain things I need to use called VUnit, OSVVM (submodule), JSON-for-VHDL (submodule) and a few other repositories created for hardware design testbench development. They are present on github but I can't clone them directly from there. This is where the problem lies. I want to have a copy of these repositories on the corporate Git of my company.

Comment: Why are you asking us to update your corporate git proxy? Since your company insists on all git access going through that proxy, it's going to need the prerequisite submodules for anything it clones. Automating proxying these things isn't hard, but since you clearly aren't administering it you're also clearly not going to be able to set this up even if you know how. Once it's done, you can just set the submodule urls to the proxy upstream after init'ing but before updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle together the commits of the 3 repositories -- for example, add two remotes `sub1` and `sub2` to your repo and run `git fetch sub1/ git fetch sub2` -- and then create a single bundle with all the commits you need.

Comment: I do not know what is bundle, is there an example that I can use for guidance on this?